# Do Azure ARM Template deployments delete host keys for a function app?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager, azure-deployment

I have written a very simple ARM template for an Azure function app, that only consists of the function app itself, a storage account and a dedicated app service plan. The app already existed in Azure and was created by hand back in the day. It had a custom
Host key configured that another service was depending on. After the ARM deployment went through, the host key was gone and the other service didn’t work anymore. I did not find a way to declare the host key in the ARM template itself so I would have never expected it to be deleted. Has anyone ever experienced the same?

Deployed using the latest azure-cli.

Answer (score 0):

It could be caused by accidentally switching from using Azure Files to not using it (or vice versa). This is driven by the `WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING` and `WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE` app settings.

Comment: Haven’t set these env vars. Will try to set them tomorrow and see if that fixes the issue. Thanks so far!

Comment: Or maybe not. According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings these settings only apply to consumption plan based apps. Mine is running on a dedicated app service plan.

Comment: You are correct, I had assumed Consumption. From Kudu Console, try looking at `D:\home\data\Functions\secrets`. Are the files there brand new or old? If new, then something caused them to get regenerated for some reason.